# Activiti: use activiti:expression to define reusable ScriptTaskListener script

Tags: groovy, activiti

I want to define script sourcecode somewhere and reuse it from multiple ScriptTaskListeners in Activiti 5.12 or later.

Assuming I have defined a processVariable `taskScript` in a previous groovy script task which contains groovy source code:

```
execution.setVariable("taskScript", 
    'def log = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger("my.Logger");log.info("works")')
```

Now I want to let an `org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.listener.ScriptTaskListener` use that code by passing it as an `activiti:expression`:

```
<activiti:taskListener event="complete" class="org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.listener.ScriptTaskListener" >
  <activiti:field name="script">
     <activiti:expression><![CDATA[${taskScript}]]></activiti:expression>
  </activiti:field>
  <activiti:field name="language" stringValue="groovy" />
</activiti:taskListener>
```

I get the Exception below:

```
javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: 
No signature of method: org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.$() 
is applicable for argument types: (Script657$_run_closure1)
```

It appears that the expression `${taskScript}` does not get evaluated before Activiti passes it to the ScriptTaskListener `script` property, rather the groovy engine tries to evaluate `${taskScript}` as a groovy script.

This however works fine:

```
<activiti:taskListener event="complete" class="org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.listener.ScriptTaskListener" >
  <activiti:field name="script">
    <activiti:string>
      def log = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger("my.Logger");
      log.info("works")
    </activiti:string>
  </activiti:field>
  <activiti:field name="language" stringValue="groovy" />
</activiti:taskListener>
```

I am quite confused why I cannot do this. Shouldn't `activiti:expression` always be evaluated before it gets applied to an `activiti:field`?

Is there a different way to reuse script code in ScriptTaskListeners?

Comment: Never used activiti, but does `<activiti:field name="script"><activiti:string><activiti:expression><![CDATA[${taskScript}]]></activiti:expression></activiti:string></activiti:field>` work?  Or maybe `<activiti:field name="script"><activiti:string><![CDATA[${taskScript}]]></activiti:string></activiti:field>`? 

Answer (score 0):

The key is how the ScriptTaskListener evaluates the expression. It does not evaluate the UEL Expression and passes that to Groovy, rather it lets only the Groovy engine evaluate the expression. We need to pass a groovy script as expression instead of a `${taskScript}` UEL expression.

It turns out that this works:

```
<activiti:expression><![CDATA[
try {
  evaluate(task.getVariable("taskScript"));
} catch (ex) {
  def log = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger("my.Logger");
  log.warn("failed to invoke taskScript", ex)
}
]]>
</activiti:expression>
```

The evaluate call **must** be nested with try..catch because an exception in a listener prevents the event from being processed, so that your processes will grind to a permanent halt.